# Pushing changes to bit bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, curl, bitbucket

I am trying to push some changes to bit bucket through a curl command(using node js) with a sequence of command

curl --insecure  --proxy-user username:password  -X PUT -u' + ' -F content=@' + 'html file' + ' -F message=' + message + ' -F branch='/path of the bit bucket repo'

Assuming, the command is going to execute five times recursively. Most of the time am getting the below error,

```
{"context":null,"message":"The merge could not
be completed because the target ref was updated mid-merge.","exceptionName":"com
.atlassian.bitbucket.scm.git.command.push.GitNonFastForwardUpdateRejectedExcepti
on"}
```

Am not able to resolve this. If any one could give me a work around on the command. I would be really great.